# Convert JSP java code

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans, initialization

I have a web application, I'm using JSP, so when I insert java code I start opening it as `<%%>` but I want to use `<%!%>` how can I do it?

There is my code:

```
  <body>
         <h1>Factorial</h1>

    <form action="" method=post>
  <input type="number" name="cantidad" min="1">
   <input type= "submit" value=submit>
     </form> 
           <% 

       String numero=request.getParameter("cantidad");

 if(numero != null){
     Integer num = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("cantidad"));
      if(num != null){
          int res =1;

         for (int s=1; s <=num; s++){
             res *=s;
         }
         out.print(res);
      }

 }


    %>
</body>
```

So, how can I do that?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to use `<%! . . . !%>` as the interpolation tag?

Comment: Yes bro, but as I know is `<%!` and `%>`

Comment: Ohhh... and how can I use it?, because if I use this tag, it conflicts part of my java code

Comment: See Elliot Frisch's answer below. `<%!` is a reserved symbol for declarations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<%! %>` is for [JSP Declarations](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaos.html).

The linked Java 5 EE Tutorial says (in part)

> A **JSP declaration** is used to declare variables and methods in a page’s scripting language.

So you'd need to declare something

```
<%!
    static final int getANumber() {
        return 101;
    }
%>
```

then you can call that function in a scriptlet. But you really should prefer to use a more modern Java web technology (and avoid scriptlets).

Comment: ooo excelent ... so my code was now   `<%!
           int res =1;
        %>` and the rest of my code on `<% ....%>`

Answer (score 1):

***All JSP files will be converted into Servlet (.java and finally .class) files by the Application server.***

**JSP Declarations:**

> <%! int count = 0; %>     ===> Declares 'count' Instance Variable inside the
>   Servlet Class generated by the Server, this variable is common for all requests, usage of this is discouraged, unless there is a strong reason.

**Scriptlets:**

> <% int count =0; %>  ===> Declares Local Variable inside service()
>   method, this variable is local for each request, so there is no problem of usage. However, scriptles inside JSP are generally considered as bad practice.

Comment: I don't use servlet... Im doing all work on JSP so I declare now `<%! int res =1; %>` and the rest of my code on `<% ....%>`

Comment: @GerardoVentas Read the first sentence again. **All** JSP(s) are compiled to a servlet.

Comment: If I don't have any servlet, JSP just run as a hidden or system servlet or somthing?

Comment: yes, your JSP file will be converted into servlet by the server.

Comment: Try throwing an `Exception`, catching it, and printing the stack trace. You'll see that there is a generated Servlet (with a machine generated class name).

Answer (score 0):

<℅!℅>, is used for just variable and method declaration.